# Iterate list over dictionary to map items

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, python-itertools

I have two files namely:

## File1:

```
CL1 AA  XX  YY  ZZ  SS \n
CL2 3_b AA
```

## File2:

```
AA  string1
AA  string2
3_b string3
```

## My expected output is:

```
CL1 AA  string1
CL1 AA  string2
CL2 3_b string3
CL2 AA  string1
CL2 AA  string2
```

For this I wrote a following code:

```
import numpy as np
print("Reading Files...")
header = open('File1', 'r')
cl = header.readlines()
infile = np.genfromtxt('File2', dtype='str', skip_header=1)
new_array = []

for j in range(len(infile)):
    for row in cl:
        element = row.split("\t")
        ele_size = len(element)
        for i in range(0, ele_size):
            if np.core.defchararray.equal(infile[j,0], element[i]):
                clust = element[0]
                match1 = infile[j,0]
                match2 = infile[j,1]
                combo = "\t".join([clust, match1, match2])
                new_array.append(combo)

np.savetxt('output.txt',new_array, fmt='%s', delimiter='\t')
```

This generates the output i desire. But since the file has some  700000 lines in file2 and some 65000 clusters, it takes a huge time to iterate. Can anyone suggest an efficient way to parse it?

Is it possible to keep first file as list and second file as dictionary? and then iterate over key values?

Comment: Questions about optimizing working code will get better answers in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is not a use case for numpy

Answer (score 1):

You should instead store a dict for File2, then when you iterate over lines in File1 you can just look up the keys in the File2 dict.  This will mean a single level `for` loop instead of three levels of `for` loops.

I don't think NumPy is going to help you with any of this--easier to ignore it and just write regular Python.  I think it will end up being quite fast.

Comment: Problem is that, my file 1 has non-uniform data. For example, in line 1 there are 6 entries, whereas in line 2 there are only 3 entries. When I read it, i use readlines and when I split each entry with tab, I am getting an list with size 6 (it counts each empty space as one element).

Comment: I don't see why that's a problem.  Just iterate over the tokens on each line.  Different counts is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something that looks roughly like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data1 = '''CL1 AA  XX  YY  ZZ  SS
CL2 3_b AA'''.split('\n')

data2 = '''AA  string1
AA  string2
3_b string3'''.split('\n')

# Store mappings that look like
#  * AA generates 'string1' and 'string2'
#  * 3_b generates 'string3'
mapping = defaultdict(list)
for line in data2:
    token, string = line.split() # you may need to change how you split the lines
    mapping[token].append(string)

result = []
# line -> CL1 AA  XX  YY  ZZ  SS
# element ^^^
# tokens      ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^
for line in data1:
    element, *tokens = line.split()
    for token in tokens[:2]: # you seem to only want 'match1' and 'match2'
        for string in mapping[token]:
            result.append([element, token, string])

for lst in result:
    print('\t'.join(lst))
```

Basically, you store the contents of "File2" in a dictionary in advance, which resembles:

```
{"AA": ["string1", "string2"], "3_b": ["string3"]}
```

Then you loop over each line of "File1"; extract the first three components; and for the latter two of those, find the corresponding string* values from the dictionary you generated in advance.

I concur with other users in suggesting that numpy is not going to be super-useful here. It probably just adds overhead for no real benefit.